# Unable to access https enabled OGC WMS service in Portal for ArcGIS 10.4.1

Tags: wms, arcgis-10.4, ogc, apache, arcgis-portal

OGC WMS service is published on WebLogic 10.3 (https enabled). We are able to access OGC WMS service deployed in web logic server through browser and secured connection was established successfully.

WebLogic is installed and configured in Windows server

[image]

While adding above https enabled OGC WMS service as an item in ArcGIS for portal getting below error.

[image]

**Few points to note-**

1. ArcGIS for Portal 10.4.1 is installed and configured in Linux SUSE Enterprise 12
2. ArcGIS Web Adaptor is sitting on Apache Tomcat 8.039 web server
3. All SSL certificates are configured properly in Portal for ArcGIS 10.4.1
4. I am able to access the https enabled OGC WMS Service successfully in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.1
5. I am able to register same OGC WMS Service with unsecured connection in Portal for ArcGIS 10.4

Comment: I can't find a reference but I have seen this case a few years ago. ESRI support told then that cascading WMS services which require username/password is not considered appropriate and therefore it is not supported. We put either MapServer or GeoServer in between to read data from protected WMS through https and basic authentication and publish it as unsecured WMS layer for ArcGIS server. The original service provider still got the right username/password to their logs and this usage was OK for them. Do you have also username/password or only https?

Comment: Thanks for the response. OGC WMS Service which we are trying to register with portal requires no username/password.

Comment: Ramp up the portal log settings and include them in your post.  Anything in the browser logs?  Perhaps also include a .HAR file into your post